# c# HtmlAgilityPack and Yahoo's HTML

Tags: javascript, c#, html-agility-pack

So I am goofing off and wrote something that first queries other websites and loads all of the pertinent stock exchange symbols and the tries to iterate through the symbols and load Yahoo's server for the latest stock price.  For some reason no matter what I try to search by using HtmlAgilityPack, I can't seem to get any pertinent info back.  I don't think there's an issue with some javascript running after the page is loaded (but I could be wrong).

The following is a generalized routine that can be tinkered with to try and get the percentage change of the stock symbol back from Yahoo:

```
                string symbol = "stock symbol"    
                string link = @"http://finance.yahoo.com/q?uhb=uh3_finance_vert&s=" + symbol;

                string data = String.Empty;
                try
                {
                    // keep in this scope so wedget and doc deconstruct themselves
                    var webget = new HtmlWeb();
                    var doc = webget.Load(link);
                    string percGrn = doc.FindInnerHtml("//span[@id='yfs_pp0_" + symbol + "']//b[@class='yfi-price-change-up']");
                    string percRed = doc.FindInnerHtml("//span[@id='yfs_pp0_" + symbol + "']//b[@class='yfi-price-change-down']");

                    // create somthing we'll nuderstand later
                    if ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(percGrn) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(percRed)) ||
                        (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(percGrn) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(percRed))) 
                        throw new Exception();

                    // adding string to empty gives string
                    string perc = percGrn + percRed;
                    bool isNegative = String.IsNullOrEmpty(percGrn);
                    double percDouble;

                    if (double.TryParse(Regex.Match(perc, @"\d+([.])?(\d+)?").Value, out percDouble))
                        data = (isNegative ? 0 - percDouble : percDouble).ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
                finally
                {
                    // now we need to check what we have and load into the datgridView
                    if (!newData_d.ContainsKey(symbol)) newData_d.Add(symbol, data);
                    else MessageBox.Show("ERROR: Duplicate stock Symbols for: " + symbol);
                }
```

And here is the extended method for FindInnerHtml:

```
// this is for the html agility class
    public static string FindInnerHtml( this HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument _doc, string _options)
    {
            var node = _doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(_options);
            return (node != null ? node.InnerText.ToString() : String.Empty);
    }
```

Any help with getting something back would be appreciated, thanks!

///////////////////////////////////////
EDIT:
///////////////////////////////////////

I highlighted the span id and then check out line 239 for where I saw 'yfi-price-change-up' reference:

[image]

Comment: For example, from [MSFT](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?uhb=uh3_finance_vert&s=msft), what value should be selected, is it '0.60%'?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: I couldn't find anything with class 'yfi-price-change-up' in the linked page in my first comment. Have no idea how did you come up with that XPath...

Comment: I just updated the question with an image, although now that I'm half awake and looking at it... it seems to be extremely padded on both sides...

Comment: Strange, in my browser class of the span is 'yfi-price-change-green', not 'yfi-price-change-up'.. Could it be that the server may return different HTML for different.. country maybe? Anyway, try using contains to when matching the span class then..

Comment: Hey har07, can you check to see if this still works?  For some reason your solution isn't working anymore and their HTML looks the same...

Comment: Nevermind, I had a memory leak... sheesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XPath successfully find the target `<span>` which contains percentage of increase (or decrease) :

```
var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?uhb=uh3_finance_vert&s=msft");
var xpath = "//span[contains(@class,'time_rtq_content')]/span[2]";
var span = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
Console.WriteLine(span.InnerText);
```

**output :**

```
(0.60%)
```

Comment: I was trying to change how you used contains('') by doing this:

Comment: string percGrn = doc.FindInnerHtml(
                        "//span[contains(@id,'yfs_pp0_" + symbol + "')]//b[contains(@class,'yfi-price-change-up')]");
                    string percRed = doc.FindInnerHtml(
                        "//span[contains(@id,'yfs_pp0_" + symbol + "')]//b[contains(@class,'yfi-price-change-down')]");

Comment: But still nothing... very frustrating.  I was trying to avoid assuming index positions like you did...

Comment: Just for historical purposes and just said screw it and assumed the index position and used two xpaths to figure out positive or negative gain like so:

Comment: string percGrn = doc.FindInnerHtml(
                        "//span[contains(@class,'time_rtq_content') and contains(@class,'up_g')]//span[2]");
                    string percRed = doc.FindInnerHtml(
                        "//span[contains(@class,'time_rtq_content') and contains(@class,'down_r')]//span[2]");